# Упростить конструкцию if else

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular

Столкнулся с такой вот конструкцией.

```
canDeactivate(): Promise<any> | boolean {
  if (this.form.dirty) {
    const confirmResult = confirm('Are you sure you want to leave this page ? ');
    if (confirmResult === true) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true
}
```

Подскажите у кого есть какие идее по упрощение этой конструкции ?   Я хотел использовать терный оператор но он сюда не подходит....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
return !this.form.dirty || confirm('Are you sure you want to leave this page?');
```